# Flink CSV file reader fails to cast a LongType into a PojoType

Tags: apache-flink

Part of the code I am trying to execute in Flink:

```scala
val pages = env.readCsvFile[(Long)]("/home/ppi.csv",
   fieldDelimiter = "\t", includedFields = Array(1))
```

I want to use `pages` for some other purpose but when I compile, Flink throws me an error message as

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>        org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.IntegerTypeInfo cannot be cast to
>        org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.PojoTypeInfo

By the way I am using the 0.9 snapshot version of Flink. Any help in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: it might make more sense to post to the flink forums/mailinglist/bug-tracker, especially as it is a snapshot version. did you try with the latest release?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

If you read from a CSV file, the return type will be a Scala tuple with all read fields. In your example, you are only reading a single field which will give a Tuple1. This is what you try to specify with the parentheses surrounding "Long":

```scala
readCsvFile[(Long)]
```

In Scala you can only specify Tuples with two or more fields using parentheses. So you need to write instead

```scala
readCsvFile[Tuple1[Long]]
```

The exception is thrown because, Flink's CSVInputFormat tries to interpret all non-Tuple types as Pojo types.

Comment: Hi Fabian. Thank you for your answer. my question is, below is the code i found from the programming guide Flink there they read the data from the CSVfile.                                                                         //read a CSV file with five fields, taking only two of them
val csvInput = env.readCsvFile[(String, Double)](
  "hdfs:///the/CSV/file",
  includedFields = Array(0, 3)) // take the first and the fourth field                                                                                                            Is csvinput is a tuple or Pojo?

Comment: The return type of that example is a Tuple2[String, Double]. Scala offers a shortcut to specify tuple types as (String, Double). However, that only works for tuples with two or more fields.

Comment: Hi Fabian. Thanks once again. Is there a way to convert Tuple1[Long] to Long in Scala? Because, i am getting an error Type mismatch expected: Long but actual:Tuple1[Long] found. when i try to use map on the input read from a CSV file? Below is my snippet                                                                                                       val pages = env.readCsvFile[Tuple1[(Long)]]("/home/vinoth/bigdata/assign10/ppi.csv", fieldDelimiter = "\t", includedFields =  Array(1))      val pagesWithRanks = pages.map(p(here is the error i get) => Page(p, 1.0 / pages.count())).Thank you.

Comment: You can implement the map function such that it accepts a Tuple1[Long] as: val pagesWithRanks = pages.map(p => Page(p._1, 1.0 / pages.count()))

Comment: By the way, you cannot use "pages.count()" directly in the map function. You have to collect that first into a value like this: "val cnt = pages.count()" and then use cnt in the map function.